# What's the most compact way of converting 96-bit integer into a string (alternatives to Base64)

Tags: integer, base64

As you might have guessed, this is for generating short URLs.

What's the best way to compact a 96-bit integer into a URL friendly short string? Is Base64 the best way or are there any alternatives?

Comment: One clarification. I'm already familiar with URL Friendly Base64. I'm looking for alternatives that will generate shorter strings. (I'm not sure if that exists, that's the reason for asking the question in the first place)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use base64 for this. It protects you from illegal characters and generates string that 'look' a little like being human-readable.

Answer (score 0):

you could calculate the bit sum

Answer (score 0):

An easy approach is a modified Base 64 encoding. The original Base 64 won't work because it uses the plus (+) and slash (/) character, which have a special meaning in URLs.

But if you replace these characters with a minus (-) and underscore(_) character, you have a nice solution.

If I'm not mistaken, there are 65 or 66 URL-safe characters. So a modified Base 64 comes pretty close to the optimum.

Comment: I agree, and that's what I've been thinking of doing. Just looking to see if there's a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

What about converting it to hexadecimal?

Comment: The generated string would be longer than the Base64 version.

Comment: Sorry - it wasn't clear that length was the main priority when I wrote that. Hex is easier than custom Base64 ;-) If you are prepared to use extended ASCII characters then you might be able to Base128 encode it.